# Is there a more elegant way to declare global variables in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

I find that, when writing a quick script, a lot of my coffee code contains blocks like this:

```
somevariable = 
someotherglobalvariable = 
yetanotherglobalvariable = undefined
```

Is there a prettier way to write this?

Comment: If you want to make this vars global you should use window as in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think  for prettier/cleaner code you should avoid chain initialisation.

```
somevariable = undefined
someotherglobalvariable = undefined 
yetanotherglobalvariable = undefined
```